# How to add row dynamicly to SFDataGrid with a Button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I am getting familiar with SFDataGrid package. I dont know how to add new row from the UI. Can someone please give me a hint? Somehow I need to update the list and get the data refreshed.

I want to press the MaterialButton an get the new Row added. It can be hard coded for now. It would help.

I use the example from syncfusion:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';



class DataGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'datagrid';
  DataGrid({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DataGridState createState() => _DataGridState();
}

class _DataGridState extends State<DataGrid> {


  List<Employee> employees = <Employee>[];
  late EmployeeDataSource employeeDataSource;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    employees = getEmployeeData();
    employeeDataSource = EmployeeDataSource(employeeData: employees);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Syncfusion Flutter DataGrid'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SfDataGrid(
            source: employeeDataSource,
            columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.fill,
            selectionMode: SelectionMode.multiple,
            columns: <GridColumn>[
              GridColumn(
                  columnName: 'id',
                  label: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        'ID',
                      ))),
              GridColumn(
                  columnName: 'name',
                  label: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text('Name'))),
              GridColumn(
                  columnName: 'designation',
                  label: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        'Designation',
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ))),
              GridColumn(
                  columnName: 'salary',
                  label: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text('Salary'))),
            ],
          ),
          MaterialButton(
            color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: (){
                /// Add new Row
          })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
  List<Employee> getEmployeeData() {
    return [
      Employee(10001, 'James', 'Project Lead', 20000),
      Employee(10002, 'Kathryn', 'Manager', 30000),
      Employee(10003, 'Lara', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10004, 'Michael', 'Designer', 15000),
      Employee(10005, 'Martin', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10006, 'Newberry', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10007, 'Balnc', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10008, 'Perry', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10009, 'Gable', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(20202, 'Grimes', 'Developer', 15000),
    ];
  }


/// Custom business object class which contains properties to hold the detailed
/// information about the employee which will be rendered in datagrid.
class Employee {
  /// Creates the employee class with required details.
  Employee(this.id, this.name, this.designation, this.salary);

  /// Id of an employee.
  final int id;

  /// Name of an employee.
  final String name;

  /// Designation of an employee.
  final String designation;

  /// Salary of an employee.
  final int salary;
}

/// An object to set the employee collection data source to the datagrid. This
/// is used to map the employee data to the datagrid widget.
class EmployeeDataSource extends DataGridSource {

  EmployeeDataSource({required List<Employee> employeeData}) {


  _employeeData = employeeData
      .map<DataGridRow>((e) => DataGridRow(cells: [
    DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'id', value: e.id),
    DataGridCell<String>(columnName: 'name', value: e.name),
    DataGridCell<String>(
        columnName: 'designation', value: e.designation),
    DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'salary', value: e.salary),
  ]))
      .toList();
}



  List<DataGridRow> _employeeData = [];

  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => _employeeData;

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((e) {
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(e.value.toString()),
          );
        }).toList());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a list to add the row,

1. make a list in the state class.

```
  List<Employee> myData = [];
```

2. create a function to fill the list.

```
  void fillTheData() {
    myData =[
      Employee(10001, 'James', 'Project Lead', 20000),
      Employee(10002, 'Kathryn', 'Manager', 30000),
      Employee(10003, 'Lara', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10004, 'Michael', 'Designer', 15000),
      Employee(10005, 'Martin', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10006, 'Newberry', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10007, 'Balnc', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10008, 'Perry', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10009, 'Gable', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(20202, 'Grimes', 'Developer', 15000),
    ];
  }
```

3. call the filldata function in the initState.
4. on the Add button, add your new row.

```
setState(() => {
  myData.add(Employee(9999, 'custom', ' some data ', 999999));
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I think I have the list to fill. It is `employees`. here full line: `List<Employee> employees = <Employee>[];` and then it's called in the ini state with: `employees = getEmployeeData();`. I was able to find it out with you help. But I can't get the list to refresh. I need something like 'refreshRows' and I can't figure out where to implement this.